# Error in App and gets force close

Tags: android, html, cordova

In my android phonegap app,sometimes i get the application error as

***Note*** when moving from one page to another page am getting this error

```
 **"A network error occurred.(file:///android_asset/www/home/home.html?userid=91)"**
```

and app gets force closed .Please guide me to solve this problem.I am also attaching the screenshot.Its cuming in android 4.x versions

[image: image of crash]

**update**

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url:url +"Status",
                data: '{"NO" : "' + no}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (r) 
                {
                     window.open("../index/index.html?id="+id);
                },
                error: function (e) 
                {
                    alert("No Network");
                }
            });
```

Comment: your question is not clear. wat r u trying to achieve?

Comment: And when do you get this error? What is your code? We can't answer this without more information...

Comment: This is unclear. can u tell us more.

Comment: see this post maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433978/keep-getting-a-network-error-occurred-when-testing-phonegap-app-with-eclipse

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535 please see this issue as same like .i will post my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Android 4.x OS when passing parameters along the URL:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17327

Comment: window.location ="page.html?"+value  i tried this but its not working for me.how to use?kindly help me

Comment: I also faced the same issue but cant help it as its an android issue... I found an alternative to this... I used localStorage instead of passing it in url... You also use localStorage

Comment: @ coder_sLay how to do use local storage can you give example

Comment: First tell me what all things you are passing in your query?

Comment: just one id...localStorage.setItem("name", userid); var a=localStorage.getItem("name");window.open("../home/home.html?userid="+a);

Comment: See bro... You cant use it like this... If you use '?' then you will get error. You have to open the home.html page and then get the userid through localStorage

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13352/discussion-between-javah-and-coder-slay)