# Link android project to external asset folder

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap to develop an application which runs on android and iOS both. These two projects will share a www folder placed outside them.
How to link the android project to the `www` folder? When I run my app, It throws `Application Error A network error occurred. (file:///android_asset/www/page/main/main.html)`

I have tried the solutions at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843181/how-to-link-assets-www-folder-in-eclipse-phonegap-android-project?rq=1) but no success

javasource:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/page/main/main.html");
```

Comment: Have you gone through all the setting of the PhoneGap project based on the information on their website.Can you provide your code of java class ? So we can tell you the solution of this error.

Comment: Yes, I do. Everything is ok when I copy the folder www into android project. But how to link to external www folder?

Comment: Ok.You don't have index.html file in your www folder.You can see from the error that it's first time always search for the index.html in www folder.and in super.loadUrl() give path like file:///android_asset/www/index.html.

Comment: Ah, yes, It just a typo when I posted my question. Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Go through this question.
They have faced similar error.May by you will get your answer.

**[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433978/keep-getting-a-network-error-occurred-when-testing-phonegap-app-with-eclipse)**

**[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758615/a-network-error-in-phonegap-on-android)**

Comment: Not similar issue. They faced the error because they try to put som parameters in the url. My issue is that the webview doesn't find the webpage

Comment: Ok.Sorry for that.try second link that i have puted in answer.

Comment: Sorry, It still doesn't work. My case seems special. I want to load the html file in `www` folder which is placed outside of project.

Comment: oh.:-( . No problem.I am right now also finding solution for this.As soon i will get the answer i will post here.

Comment: Last One: Try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223674/loading-html-file-from-local-folder-into-webview

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution at this blog: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/02/16/linked-source-files-across-phonegap-projects-on-osx/